# SQL Oracle - Replace character in string between two vowels

Tags: sql, oracle, regexp-replace

I already read all REGEXP_REPLACE documentation, but didn't found anything that I looking for. I want to replace a specificate charater between two vowels to another charater.

Example:

> String: abcdeZebca
>   Output: abcdeSebca

The letter Z was replaced by S, cause its was between two vowels. Thats possible in SQL Oracle?

Comment: Clear as mud. The character b (and c and d) is between two vowels, a and e. (You can't disagree, sorry:  **a**bcd**e**...  ; b, c and d are between a and e.) Perhaps you mean IMMEDIATELY between two vowels? Then: where do the "specificate" (you probably mean either "specific" or "specified") characters come from? Are they in a table? Are they a user input? etc. And what should they be replaced with? A single example does not constitute a problem specification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you didn't catch the bit about backreferences in the docs though:

```
SELECT
  REGEXP_REPLACE(yourcolumn, '([aeiou])Z([aeiou])', '\1S\2')
FROM 
  yourtable
```

Explained:

[aeiou] means match any single vowel. Surrounding it in brackets means "and remember what you found into a numbered slot, starting with 1" slots are numbered from left to right throughout the entire expression - each (brackets expression) gets its own number

Hence the full expression means:
- find any vowel and store in slot 1
- followed by Z
- followed by any vowel and store in slot 2

The replacement string is:
- the contents of slot 1
- S
- the contents of slot 2

Hence

```
aZe -> aSe
eZi -> eSi
```

And so on..

Comment: you should replace `Z` with `.` ..to match any character between 2 vowels..

Comment: He said he wants to replace a specific character between two vowels, not ANY character. My initial thought is he wants to change americaniZed English words to angliciSed versions.. if you recogni[z/s]e what I mean :)

Comment: Here is something that will NOT work though, given the limitations of Oracle regular expressions:  replace all occurrences of Z with S in `'eZeZe'` (expected output: `'eSeSe'`). In Oracle, this can only be done in two passes, it can't be done in a single pass.

Comment: Nice answer. Worked nice! Thx!

Comment: @Adolfok3 - did it work on the input `'eZeZe'`? That would be interesting!

Comment: Nope. I had to validate it on a loop, inside of the loop calling the function.